# Responsive image with text on the bottom bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble with css for aligning text below a responsive image. please see the image below.

[image]

infra is the image and the text below Infrastructure is the text.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-15 ">

    <a href="https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/SitePages/Home.aspx"> <img src="https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteAssets/Icons/FM&A.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Image"></a>
    <p style="color: #5081D9;">Infrastructure</p>

  </div>
```

I am using bootstrap to make the image responsive with the class "img-responsive" . how do i adjust the text below accordingly.

Please see my CSS

```html
 .col-xs-15,
        .col-sm-15,
        .col-md-15,
        .col-lg-15 {
            position: relative;
            min-height: 1px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }

        .col-xs-15 {
            width: 20%;
            float: left;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .col-sm-15 {
                width: 20%;
                float: left;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 300px) {
            .col-md-15 {
                width: 20%;
                float: left;
            }
```

Comment: You want to place text below the image?

Comment: Does `col-md-15` exist in bootstrap?

Comment: yes the text needs to be right under the image and yes col-md-15 is there in bootstrap

Comment: sorry col-md-15 is not available in bootstrap

Comment: oh yes it's a custom one i have added forever ago. My bad!. Updated the Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image url is not working provided with the code. But there is a possible way you can do it something similar. First of all you need to give image width:100%; so the image automatically attain the width of the parent container. Example:

```
 .col-xs-15 img,
        .col-sm-15 img,
        .col-md-15 img,
        .col-lg-15 img {
            width:100%;
        }
```

Now you can align text according by using css property: text-align: center; 
Example:

```
 .col-xs-15 p,
            .col-sm-15 p,
            .col-md-15 p,
            .col-lg-15 p {
                text-align:center;
            }
```

This will dynamically align the text according to the parent container.

But there is a better approach. Assign a new class to this section. Example:

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-15 img-box">

    <a href="https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/SitePages/Home.aspx"> <img src="https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteAssets/Icons/FM&A.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Image"></a>
    <p style="color: #5081D9;">Infrastructure</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

So after adding new class you can use the following css:

```
.img-box img{
       width:100%;

}
.img-box p {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple and elegant solution in **Bootstrap**: **Figures**.

Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/figures/